# Proving that $(a,b)$ is $F_{\sigma},\forall a,b\in\mathbf{R}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, infinity

I am required to prove that the interval $(a,b)$ is a $F_{\sigma}$-set i.e. it can be written as a union of countably many closed sets in $\mathbf{R}$.

**The following is my attempt so far.**

> I did not have any credible ideas in the beginning so i decided to
>   examine the special case for $(0,1)$ and proceeded as follows
>   \begin{align*} (0,1) &=
>  \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\cup\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right)\\
>  &=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,a_{n+1}]\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[b_n,b_{n+1}]
>  \\ \end{align*} $$\text{where }a_n =
>  \left\{\frac{1}{n+1}\right\}\text{ and } b_n =
>  \left\{1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right\}$$ It then occured to me that
>   $(0,1)\cong(a,b)$ where one possible bijection $f:(0,1)\to(a,b)$ is
>   defined as follows $$f(x) = x(b-a)+a$$ consequently we have (**I am certain that i have computed the following correctly**)
>   $$f(a_n) = f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{b+an}{n+1}$$ 
>   $$f(b_{n}) = f\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{bn+a}{n+1}$$ 
>   $$f(a_{n+1}) = f\left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right) = \frac{b+a(n+1)}{n+2}$$ 
>   $$f(b_{n+1}) = f\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right) = \frac{b(n+1)+a}{n+2}$$
>
> which leads to the following conjecture
>
> $$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[f(a_n),f(a_{n+1})]\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[f(b_n),f(b_{n+1})]$$
>
> Now i am fairly confident that this works since 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = \frac{b+an}{n+1} = \frac{b/n+a}{1+1/n} =
>  a$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n) = \frac{bn+a}{n+1} =
>  \frac{a/n+b}{1+1/n} = b$$

**My only problem then is how do i articulate the above story as a proper argument and preferably a simple argument**.

This is where i am stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your argument already looks ok (but you should write $[a_{n+1},a_n]$ instead of $[a_n,a_{n+1}]$, and the same goes for $\big[f(a_n),f(a_{n+1})\big]$, which should be $\big[f(a_{n+1}),f(a_n)\big]$), and does not need any more elaboration in my opinion.  What I don't understand about your question is what is your confusion.  The part after "which leads to the following conjecture" follows immediately from your calculations of $f(a_n)$ and $f(b_n)$.

Comment: However, I do have one remark about your question regarding a "simple argument."  Your method is, in my opinion, unnecessarily complicated.  If I were to do it, then I would prove the claim in the following manner.  Let $N$ be a positive integer greater than $\dfrac{2}{b-a}$.  Define for each integer $n\geq N$, $$K_n:=\left[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}\right]\,.$$  Then, it follows that $K_n$ is a closed set and $$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=N}^\infty\,K_n\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski Why choose an $N>2/(a-b)$ though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem here is that your formulas for $f^{\rightarrow}([a_n,a_{n+1}])$ are so complicated.

Instead, you should reduce the problem to the $(0,1)$ case, and then solve that.  How about this lemma:

> Suppose $(a,b)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is such that there exists a continuous $g\in\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g^{\leftarrow}((0,1))=(a,b)$.  If $(0,1)$ is $F_{\sigma}$, then so is $(a,b)$.

To prove the lemma follows very quickly from the definitions.  You will need the fact that the preimage of any closed set under a continuous function is closed, and that preimages preserve unions.

Then use $g=f^{-1}$ (to borrow your notation) and write $$(0,1)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\left[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right]\cup\left[1-\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]\right)}$$

(I've taken the liberty of redistributing your unionands; there are multiple equivalent ways to do this.)